# ERROR - Turborepo shadcn UI - 'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: next.js13, turborepo

did anyone else got similar error with me? Actually this error didnt make any problems in my code. The code works fine. but its disturbing me.

[image]

what i've done:

- I just want to implement my code from package

  ```html
  import { Button } from 'ui';

  export default function Page() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button>test</Button>
      </>
    );
  }
  ```
- this is my package.json in apps/app (next.js)

  ```html
      {
        "name": "web",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
          "dev": "next dev",
          "build": "next build",
          "start": "next start",
          "lint": "next lint"
        },
        "dependencies": {
          "next": "^13.4.1",
          "react": "^18.2.0",
          "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
          "ui": "workspace:*"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "@total-typescript/ts-reset": "^0.4.2",
          "@types/node": "^17.0.12",
          "@types/react": "^18.0.22",
          "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.7",
          "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
          "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
          "postcss": "^8.4.25",
          "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
          "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
          "typescript": "^4.5.3"
        }
  }
  ```
- this is my next.config.js

  ```html
  module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    transpilePackages: ["ui"],
  };
  ```